# Структуры, нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу

Tags: c++, c

Всегда было удобнее разбирать по примеру, поэтому:
Есть часть кода, которая не работает:

```
typedef struct
{
    int pr;
    int dat;
}Node;

Node* arr[5];

void foo(int pr, int dat)
{
    arr[1] -> dat = dat;     //интересная
    arr[1] -> pr = pr;       //часть
}
```

а вот в таком виде уже работает:

```
 typedef struct
    {
        int pr;
        int dat;
    }Node;

    Node* arr[5];

    void foo(int pr, int dat)
    {
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));  //та 
    node->pr = pr;                              //самая 
    node->dat = dat;                            //интересная 
    arr[1] = node;                              //часть
    }
```

ну понятно, функцию foo вызываю из main-а, передаю два каких-то int-овых значения. Так зачем создавать этот node, его же потом очистить надо (free)? Почему нельзя сразу положить в массив? Заранее спасибо, когда разберусь, 100% буду очень рад и благодарен)!

Comment: А как вы собираетесь в этом node что-то хранить, если не будете его сначала создавать?

Comment: а я и не хочу ничего в нем хранить, он нужен, чтобы записать pr и dat в arr, тк напрямую не могу записывать, но почему - не знаю

Comment: ¿Т.е. как это - не хотите? Вы же в обоих примерах присваиваете значения полям `dat` и `pr` экземпляра объекта `Node`. Разница только в том, что в первом случае ни одного объекта `Node` не создаете. У вас есть только массив из 5 указателей на `Node`. Обращаться к полям и методам можно только у созданного объекта.

Comment: да! вот оно! спасибо! надо было спать идти и на свежую голову этим заниматься... какая-же тупая ошибка... да и вопрос( еще раз спасибо!

Comment: интересная часть совсем не интересна - функция foo "заточена" только на один элемент из массива.

Comment: ну я код программы хорошо исковеркал, оставил только ту часть, которую не понял, а так, конечно, там не arr[1], а arr[i % SZ], просто пихать реальный код... зачем

Comment: @user7860670 Что с клавиатурой? Испанская? XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Да, вот сейчас учу испанский язык, и их подход с обрамлением вопросительных и восклицательных предложений сразу с обеих сторон мне очень понравился.

Comment: @user7860670 Хех ;) Как вы его в русской раскладке печатаете? `Menu` + `?` + `?`? XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor ¿ - Alt + 0191 ¡ - Alt + 0161

Comment: @user7860670 А, винда XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не делайте массив нулевых указателей, а создайте массив структур.

```
Node arr[5]; // ! НЕ указатели

void foo(int pr, int dat)
{
    arr[1] . dat = dat;     //интересная
    arr[1] . pr = pr;       //часть
}
```

Comment: благодаря вашему ответу и предыдущему комменту смог разобраться, спасибо!

Comment: @HMS_TRINIDAD, тебе нужно разобраться в том, что такое куча и чем она отличается от стека. В первом случае у тебя вообще UB, поскольку ты затрёшь какие-то данные.